# Error in while compiling python code using sklearn.utils.shuffle

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn and ran into this issue:

```
  File "C:\python\lib\sklearn\__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\python\lib\sklearn\base.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT
  File "C:\python\lib\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
  File "__init__.pxd", line 918, in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash
ValueError: numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 216 from C header, got 192 from PyObject
```

how can i resolve this error?

Comment: Hi ! I see that you are a new contributor. Your Question could be improved with some context. Can you explain how you came across this issue ? Thanks !

Comment: @Auyer  am writing a script but couldn't compile because of this error

Comment: in Python there is no compilation like in C/C++/Java, you run code.

Comment: maybe you have to update `sklearn` or `numpy` (or other module) because there are some incompatibilities.

Comment: @furas i recently installed both sklearn n numpy library so they both are on latest version

Answer (score 1):

So i got the solution, i did update the numpy library by using 
pip install numpy --upgrade 
, this updated the numpy but when i go in python it was pointing to the old version, so i simply remove previous numpy library from
python/lib & python/lib/site-packages
and then install it again. Now it's working!